# dependency resolution errors

Tags: android, flutter

I faced  this problem , when I try to run the app

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder$LimitedInputStream found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractProtobufList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.BooleanArrayList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteBufferWriter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteOutput found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$ArraysByteArrayCopier found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$BoundedByteString found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$ByteArrayCopier found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$ByteIterator found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$CodedBuilder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$LeafByteString found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$LiteralByteString found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$Output found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$SystemByteArrayCopier found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$AbstractBufferedEncoder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$ArrayEncoder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$ByteOutputEncoder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutOfSpaceException found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutputStreamEncoder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.DoubleArrayList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExperimentalApi found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryFactory found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite$ObjectIntPair found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FieldSet found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FieldSet$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FieldSet$FieldDescriptorLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FloatArrayList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$Builder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$DefaultInstanceBasedParser found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableBuilder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableMessage found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableMessage$ExtensionWriter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableMessageOrBuilder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtensionDescriptor found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$GeneratedExtension found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$MethodToInvoke found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$SerializedForm found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.IntArrayList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$BooleanList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$DoubleList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$EnumLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$EnumLiteMap found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$FloatList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$IntList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$ListAdapter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$ListAdapter$Converter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$LongList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$Converter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$EntryAdapter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$IteratorAdapter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$SetAdapter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$ProtobufList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyField found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyField$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyField$LazyEntry found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyField$LazyIterator found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyFieldLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList$ByteArrayListView found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList$ByteStringListView found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LongArrayList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MapEntryLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MapEntryLite$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MapEntryLite$Metadata found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MapFieldLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite$Builder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MessageLiteOrBuilder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MessageLiteToString found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MutabilityOracle found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MutabilityOracle$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.NioByteString found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.NioByteString$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Parser found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
> Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ProtobufArrayList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)

```
 Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

Comment: It'll be helpful if you share the code

Comment: which code , do you men dependences or what ??

Comment: Try running cleanBuildCache and use —no-build-cache flag

Comment: Welcome to SO, please confirm your gradle version, java version, flutter and dart version. share these version codes. looks like compatibility issues of gradle with java

Comment: Source code, or the patch which you think might be giving this error

Comment: Also check if your app runs by opening android module only `Tools->Flutter->Open for Editing in Android Studio` . clean and rebuild for running the project.

Comment: this problem happen when , try  to import barcode_scan package and firebase package  !!

Comment: [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1052], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.2.0 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision b22742018b (4 weeks ago), 2021-05-14 19:12:57 -0700
    • Engine revision a9d88a4d18
    • Dart version 2.13.0

Comment: √] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

Comment: You are using more than one libraries which both have a same class or using different versions of same library. Please check.

Comment: yes  I noticed that, the conflict between barcode_scan: ^3.0.1 and  firebase_auth: ^1.3.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.2.0
  firebase_core: ^1.2.0

Comment: Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite found in the following modules: jetified-protobuf-java-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.14.0), jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)